# How to connect each SQL instance to get SQL server version updated into the temp table?

Tags: sql-server

```
-- Trying to get SQL Server verion with CMS information. Run this in SQLCMD mode

-- Create temp table for Instance
CREATE TABLE #Instance_list(Server_Group_Name nvarchar(12), Server_Name nvarchar(50), Instance_Description nvarchar(512))
GO
-- Get Instance list from CMS
INSERT INTO #Instance_list 
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(12), groups.name) AS Server_Group_Name
     ,CONVERT(nvarchar(50), svr.server_name) AS Server_Name
     , CONVERT(nvarchar(512),svr.description) as Instance_Description

FROM msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups_internal groups 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal svr
ON groups.server_group_id = svr.server_group_id 
GO
-- Add SQL version column
ALTER TABLE  #Instance_list ADD Instance_Version nvarchar(512)
-- Loop each instance
DECLARE @Instance nvarchar(50)
DECLARE Instance_List_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [Server_Name] from #Instance_list
OPEN Instance_List_cursor

 FETCH NEXT FROM Instance_List_cursor 
 INTO @Instance

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 -- How to connect each SQL instance to get SQL server version updated in to the temp table?
PRINT @Instance
DECLARE @SQLVERSION nvarchar(512)
--:Connect @Instance

SET @SQLVERSION = (SELECT @@VERSION FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info)
PRINT @SQLVERSION
--:CONNECT CMS_INSTANCE
-- UPDATE #Instance_list SET [Instance_Version] = @SQLVERSION WHERE Server_Name = @Instance

 FETCH NEXT FROM Instance_List_cursor INTO @Instance
 END 

CLOSE Instance_List_cursor
DEALLOCATE Instance_List_cursor

SELECT * FROM #Instance_list
GO


DROP TABLE #Instance_list
```

How to connect each SQL instance to get SQL server version updated into the temp table?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) - [`Get-DbaCmsRegServerGroup`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaCmsRegServerGroup)

> Gets list of Server Groups objects stored in SQL Server Central Management Server (CMS).

If you have multiple servers to connect, you can use `foreach` to loop through each servers and store the result into a variable.

You can even write to a database using `ConvertTo-DbaDataTable` and `Write-DbaDataTable`

Comment: to save writing the loop, I think you can do something like  `Get-DbaCmsRegServerGroup | Get-DbaInstanceProperty -InstanceProperty ProductVersion` ... on a tiny keyboard so can't test at the moment.